# Navigation using Custom Navigation Bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

It's been a few weeks since I started coding in Flutter and I have the task of designing a Custom Bottom Navigation Bar alongside its functionality. Although I have successfully managed to replicate the Bottom Nav Bar exactly as the design, I cannot get it to navigate to other pages. I'm a little short on ideas as to how I can get this part of it to work. What happens right now is that whenever I click on any of the options below, the Navigation does not work. I would also like to declare that this is my first time working with Bottom Navigation Bars and it would be really helpful if someone could shed some light on how this can be achieved. The code is below:

The Home Screen is set as the home route(`home: HomeScreen()`). The bottom navigation bar is right at the end of this widget.

```
class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final textScaleFactor = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor * 1.2;

    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        // backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(236, 236, 248, 1),
        // foregroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(236, 236, 248, 1),
        // backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        elevation: 0,
        toolbarHeight: 180,
        title: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Welcome',
              textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
              style:
                  TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8), fontSize: 20),
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: height * 0.18,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: height * 0.01),
              // color: Colors.amber,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Eli Avon',
                        textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 40),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: width * 0.4,
                        height: height * 0.06,
                        // color: Colors.pink,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            const Icon(Icons.location_on,
                                color: Colors.green, size: 35),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      EdgeInsets.only(top: height * 0.0098),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Estimated Time',
                                    textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                // SizedBox(height: height * 0.01),
                                Text(
                                  'Park Street',
                                  textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12),
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: width * 0.7,
                    height: height * 0.055,
                    margin:
                        EdgeInsets.only(top: height * 0.02, left: width * 0.02),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.02),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        boxShadow: const [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.greenAccent,
                              // spreadRadius: 5,
                              blurRadius: 5,
                              offset: Offset(0, 2))
                        ]),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        const Icon(
                          Icons.search_outlined,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: width * 0.04),
                        Text(
                          'Search',
                          textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6),
                              fontSize: 25),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: height * 1,
        width: width * 1,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/Rectangle 392.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: height * 0.02),
              child: Categories(),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: height * 0.025),
            Discount(),
            SizedBox(height: height * 0.025),
            PopularDeals(),
            TopSeller(),
            SizedBox(height: height * 0.025),
            RecentItems(),
            SizedBox(height: height * 0.025),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: height * 0.1,
              color: const Color.fromRGBO(251, 243, 231, 1),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Oops..Ran out of it',
                  textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey[600],
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: height * 0.15),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavigation(),    //The Bottom Navigation Bar
    );
  }
}
```

The code for the Bottom Navigation Bar

```
class CustomBottomNavigationState extends State<CustomBottomNavigation> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    // TODO: implement build
    return Container(
      height: height * 0.12,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Container(
              width: width * 0.85,
              height: height * 0.06,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey, blurRadius: 5, offset: Offset(0, 2))
                  ]),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: width * 0.35,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.02),
                    // color: Colors.red,
                    child: Row(
                      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () =>
                              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/cart-screen'),
                          
                          child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/Icon awesome-shopping-cart.png'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: width * 0.1),
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
                              .pushNamed('/dashboard-screen'),
                          
                          child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/Icon ionic-ios-settings.png'),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: width * 0.35,
                    // padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: width * 0.02),
                    // color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.06),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
                                .pushNamed('/notification-screen'),
                            
                            child: Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/Icon awesome-bell.png'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: width * 0.1),
                        InkWell(
                            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
                                .pushNamed('/profile-screen'),
                            child: Image.asset('assets/images/rkwxkca7.png'))
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home-screen'),
              child: Container(
                height: height * 0.075,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    boxShadow: const [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          blurRadius: 5,
                          offset: Offset(0, 2))
                    ],
                    border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        width: 2,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                child: Center(
                    child:
                        Image.asset('assets/images/Icon ionic-ios-home.png')),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What would I need to do to fix this? Also, is this how it's supposed to be done?

PS. Below is the NavBar in question just in case someone wanted to see how it looks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is coming from

```dart
Positioned(
    child: InkWell(
    onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home-screen'),
```

This will interact the full space from stack. In this case you can use `Align` and wrap `InkWell` with `SizedBox` by providing width.

```dart
Align( // you can also use Positioned widget by providing left/right and bottom/top value
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  child: SizedBox(
    width: 48, // as you prefer
    height: height * 0.075,
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(...
```

Also if your images cause issue, provide `fit:`,`width`,`height` .

But based on design I will encourage you to check about **notch bottomNavigationBar**.

Here are some good question about notch shape

- [bottomNavigationBar notch transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59455684/10157127)
- [How to add Floating action Button in Bottom Navigation Bar Center with notch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55727315/10157127)

Comment: Will this solve the issue with Navigation?

Comment: I see a page transition kind of thing but it ends up navigating at the homescreen no matter what Icon I click on.

Comment: As I tested your code, I've found this issue, It is possible that others' widget may cause different issue. But this solves this case.